# Why samba maintains source code version source3 and source4?

Tags: samba

There are two source tree in samba with name source3 and source4. 
Can someone let me know the difference between source3 and source4 folder?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple google search of "samba source3 source4" gives several relevant results.

The first result for me is :
  https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2016-July/201182.html
which states (I just give a small relevant excerpt):

```
"(...) They are historical artifacts from the original
split due to the attempt a rewrite of Samba with Samba4.

All the source code is Samba4, whether in source3 or
source4 directories. They may be considered historical
placement showing where they originally came from. As
they are merged into one, the code gets moved into the
top-level lib/ util/ etc. directories. (...)"
```

So little by little those 2 trees will disappear and move to those top-level directories. But for now there is still some not-yet-merged code (all Samba4, despite the 2 names).

Comment: Thanks for reply . source3 builds smbclient and we are able to use SMB2.0 and SMB 3.0 . source 4 builds smbclient4 and we are unable to use SMB 2.0 and SMB3.0 . Any idea How to set SMB 2.0 and SMB3.0 protocol with smbclient4 binary.